# % Purity Calculation

Tags: acid-base

An impure sample of calcium oxalate with a mass of 0,803g, is titrated with 15,70cm3 of a 0,101 potassium permanganate

How do I calculate the % purity of the calcium carbonate in the original sample

Comment: There seems to be an inconsistency in your question. You presumably want to calculate the % purity of the calcium oxalate, not calcium carbonate.

Answer (score 1):

Find the number of mols that would react with 15.70ml of 0.101 molar potassium permanganate. Then convert it to grams.

Then percentage purity=(x/.803)*100. Where x is the value you calculated above.